# Sorting an array along its last dimension, and undoing the sorting

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

In my current project, I have a D-dimensional array. For the sake of exposition, we can assume D=2, but the code should work with arbitrarily high dimensions. I need to run some operations on this matrix when it is sorted according to its last dimension, and subsequently reverse the sorting on the matrix.

The first part of sorting the matrix is relatively simple:

```
import numpy as np

D = 2
matrix = np.random.uniform(low=0.,high=1.,size=tuple([5]*D))
matrix_sorted = np.sort(matrix,axis=-1)
```

This code snippet sorts the matrix according to the last dimension, but does not remember how the array was sorted, and consequently does not allow me to revert the sorting. Alternatively, I could get the sorted indices with the following line:

```
sorted_indices = np.argsort(matrix,axis=-1)
```

Unfortunately, these indices do not seem to be very useful. I am not sure how I can use these sorted indices to (a) sort the matrix, and (b) undo the sorting in the case for general D. A simple approach would be to create a for-loop over all rows for the `D=2` case (in this case, we sorted across the columns), but since I want the code to work for arbitrary dimensions, hard-coding nested for-loops is not really an option.

Do you have any elegant suggestions on how I could tackle this issue?

Comment: Why not just store two lists... the unsorted one and the sorted one....

Comment: Because I need to do some operations on the sorted array, which should persist after undoing the sorting. These operations unfortunately require that the array is sorted.

Comment: Then store the sorted array before the operations....

Comment: I'm not sure how saving the initial array helps in any way. Imagine it like this: I have an array [[3,2,1],[2,3,5]]. I want to sort it, so I obtain [[1,2,3],[2,3,5]] (the first row is reversed, the second remains the same). Then I do some complex operations, and I obtain [[7,8,1],[5,6,2]]. Now I want to revert the sorting, so the goal should be [[1,8,7],[5,6,2]]. I do of course store the initial array, but this doesn't help undoing the sorting.

Comment: The [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) provide a nice example of using the results from `argsort()` to obtain the sorted matrix -- `np.take_along_axis(matrix, sorted_indices, axis=-1)`

Comment: @MarkM: Thank's, I'll check that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, after following [Mark M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-m)'s suggestion, and reading up on some other StackOverflow answers continuing from there, the answer seems to be as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# Create the initial random matrix
D               = 2
matrix          = np.random.uniform(low=0.,high=1.,size=tuple([5]*D))

# Get the sorting indices
sorting         = np.argsort(matrix,axis=-1)

# Get the indices for unsorting the matrix
reverse_sorting = np.argsort(sorting,axis=-1)

# Sort the initial matrix
matrix_sorted   = np.take_along_axis(matrix, sorting, axis=-1)

# Undo the sorting
matrix_unsorted = np.take_along_axis(matrix_sorted, reverse_sorting, axis=-1)
```

The trick consists of two steps: `np.take_along_axis` allows us to sort arbitrarily-dimensional matrices according to the indices we get from `np.argsort`, and sorting the indices gives us the set of indices required to undo the sorting again with `np.take_along_axis`. I can do the desired complex operations between the penultimate and ultimate steps. Perfect!